# Binding a VB.NET label.text to an object property

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

I want to have a label in a form whose text value changes depending upon the value of an instance of a class. It looks like I can bind the text value of the label to an object dataSource. When I try this it does not seem to work.

```
Me.Label4.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", Me.ItemInfoBindingSource, "ItemNumber", True, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
```

My itemInfoBindingSource:

```
Me.ItemInfoBindingSource.DataSource = GetType(CFP.ItemInfo)
```

and the class definition:

```
Public Class ItemInfo
    Public Property ItemNumber As String = "rename"
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property FileLocation As String
    Public Property CompileHistory As List(Of CompileHistory)
End Class
```

I think what I have done is to bind to a class, not an instance of a class. Thinking about it, what I really want to do is bind an instance of a class to a label... How?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is possible, but you need to raise an event to let the label know that the property has changed.  If you were using a type like a BindingList, this would be done automatically, but **you're trying to bind to a `String` which doesn't raise PropertyChanged events**.

To add the event to your class:

- Change your class definition to implement INotifyPropertyChanged
- Add the corresponding PropertyChanged event
- Change the auto-implemented property to an expanded property and raise the event.

Here's the result of these changes for just the ItemNumber property in your class:

```
Public Class ItemInfo
    Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _itemNumber As String = "rename"
    Public Property ItemNumber As String
        Get
            Return _itemNumber
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _itemNumber = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, 
                New System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("ItemNumber"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, 
        e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) _
        Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
End Class
```

I added a text box and label to a form, added the data binding in the `Form.Load` event, added a field called ItemInfoBindingSource of type ItemInfo, and updated the ItemNumber in the `TextBox.TextChanged` event.

```
Private ItemInfoBindingSource As New ItemInfo

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me.ItemInfoBindingSource, "ItemNumber")
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    ItemInfoBindingSource.ItemNumber = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Now, when you type in the text box, ItemNumber.Set is called, and raises an event to let anything listening know that it's been changed.  The label is listening, and it updates its Text property so that you can see the new value.

Comment: Thanks!  Just what i was looking for today.